# Dúvida função set python

Tags: python, map, set

Estava fazendo uma questão do hacker rank que pede para mostrar o segundo valor de uma lista ( Runner up score )

Fiz meu código assim:

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

copia_lista = arr.copy()

def remove_repetidos(lista):
  l = []
   for i in lista:
      if i not in l:
        l.append(i)
l.sort()
return l
x = []

x = remove_repetidos(copia_lista)
print(sorted(x, reverse=True)[1])
```

Pesquisando achando uma solução bem simplificada, mostrada no código abaixo:

```
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())

print(sorted(list(set(arr)))[-2])
```

Gostaria de entender o que é feito na função map e o que é feito na função list(set(arr)))

Comment: `list(set(arr))` só está "economizando variáveis", fazendo tudo "de uma vez". Se fosse em 3 linhas: 1- `s = set(arr)` 2- `x = list(s)` e 3- `print(sorted(x)[-2])` ficaria mais fácil entender? Pois é isso que essa linha faz. Já o `map` vai chamar `int` para cada elemento da lista retornada por `split`, veja mais detalhes [aqui](/q/414322/112052)

Comment: Se bem que no seu caso nem precisaria de `list`, poderia fazer direto `sorted(set(arr))[-2]`

Comment: mas o que faz a função set?

Comment: Um set não permite elementos duplicados: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set - por isso ele substitui a função remove_repetidos